# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Open Data Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Yule's disturbed pendulum time series example](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/yules-disturbed-pendulum-time-series-example)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Public domain paintings database](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4250/public-domain-paintings-database)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How do I get a full list of datasets available on Data.Gov using the CKAN API?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-get-a-full-list-of-datasets-available-on-data-gov-using-the-ckan-api)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Open dataset for the number of pets per country](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4198/open-dataset-for-the-number-of-pets-per-country)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Applying filters to headers in a huge CSV file](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/applying-filters-to-headers-in-a-huge-csv-file)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Monthly data in Google Trends](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4234/monthly-data-in-google-trends)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Open downloadable recipe database?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/open-downloadable-recipe-database)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Collecting Canadian postal address information](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4189/collecting-canadian-postal-address-information)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [where can I find gov datasets (from data.gov, bea etc) in MySQL format?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4229/where-can-i-find-gov-datasets-from-data-gov-bea-etc-in-mysql-format)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Best place to publish my Android app's Google Play statistics?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4275/best-place-to-publish-my-android-apps-google-play-statistics)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---